What caused the premature loss of Super Heavy Booster 10 on IFT-3?
We are told that engine failures caused the booster to be underpowered during landing. In that case, one would expect the booster to slam into the sea. Instead, telemetry cut our at 463m above sea level. No explanation has been given for this.

On SpaceX homepage they first mentioned what happened during the flight.

The booster then continued to descend until attempting its landing burn, which commands the same 13 engines used during boostback to perform the planned final slowing for the rocket before a soft touchdown in the water, but the six engines that shut down early in the boostback burn were disabled from attempting the landing burn startup, leaving seven engines commanded to start up with two successfully reaching mainstage ignition. The booster had lower than expected landing burn thrust when contact was lost at approximately 462 meters in altitude over the Gulf of Mexico and just under seven minutes into the mission.

Then in the next paragraph the mention that the cause of failure was most likely due to a filter blockage. The booster exploded 462 meters in the air because of the flight termination system (FTS)

The most likely root cause for the early boostback burn shutdown was determined to be continued filter blockade where liquid oxygen is supplied to the engines, leading to a loss of inlet pressure in engine oxygen turbopumps.


It's also worth mentioning that people who watch the program more closely like CSI Starbase posit that the reason for the filter blockage was ice that found its way into the filter due to intense slosh in the booster. The slosh was due to the violent rolling seen on the webcast, and that is hypothesised to be due to the hot-staging ring unintentionally separating and spoiling the aerodynamics of the booster.

@dsdy120 I think it is quite certain that the hot stage ring separated since the shadow of the hot stage ring on the flaps of super heavy disappeared only after the booster starting turning rapidly.

we're deriving our conclusions from the same video, but in any case until someone from SpaceX weighs in on the topic, Zach's hypothesis remains a hypothesis, no matter how convincing. And I am personally convinced.
